# Autolayout issue with iOS 8.1.3

Tags: ios, ios8.1, ios6.1

When we update constraint in cellForRowAtIndexPath? Then table jerks while scrolling. What is the best optimum solution to this issue? Thanks

Comment: This question does not clearly describes the issue. Try posting some code or explaining with more details

Answer (score 0):

call `[cell setNeedDisplay]` for your cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method
and implement `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method inside the cell class.